# JSSOR Slider - page aligning left in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, slider

**UPDATE 10.03.14:**
Here's a screenshot: http://www.thomasgsullivan.com/ipad.PNG

---

Hi I'm a graphic & web designer, but the only sites I actually "build" are my own portfolios, all WYSIWYG with dreamweaver... so I'm new to all of this.

I have a website here: thomasgsullivan.com which works fine enough across all devices.

I'm working on an update here: http://www.thomasgsullivan.com/home.html#about

Everything works fine on the computer, but in iOS it's aligning left, and the JSSOR slider itself even more so.

here's the code:

```
    <table width="1000" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

```
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: pointer; position: relative; width: 1000px; height: 400px;
        overflow: hidden;">
        <div><img u="image" src="img/slide1.gif"/></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="img/slide2.gif"/></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="img/slide3.gif"/></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="img/slide4.gif"/></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="img/slide5.gif"/></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Arrow Left -->
    <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora03l" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 166px; left: -3px;">
    </span>
    <!-- Arrow Right -->
    <span u="arrowright" class="jssora03r" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 166px; right: -3px">
    </span>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
</div>
<!-- Jssor Slider End --></td>
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated, thanks!

PS: I know there are 160 errors on the page... but those are all alt tags and shouldn't effect this I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a table to align element center.
The style 'margin: 0 auto;' also works to align element center.

Please try to remove table element and replace,

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; width: 1000px; height: 400px;">
```

with

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 1000px; height: 400px;">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply jssor!   

I removed the table, but the slideshow is still shifting left...

Comment: screenshot added above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help jssor, I found the issue and it had nothing to do with the slide show, I had a 1000px line that was throwing off the whole layout for some reason... I removed that and everything works perfectly.